# XML Decentralization not working in Unity iOS build which working in Windows

Tags: ios, xml, unity-game-engine, serialization, xml-deserialization

I am getting details for setting up UI and message through XML placed in a custom folder of the build. Its working fine in Windows build, not in iOS. I am attaching the Script used.

XML Operation

```
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Xml;

public class XMLOperations
{
    public static void Serialize(object item, string path)
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(item.GetType());
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(path);
        serializer.Serialize(writer.BaseStream, item);
        writer.Close();
    }

    public static T Deserialize<T>(string path)
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path);
        T deserialized = (T)serializer.Deserialize(reader.BaseStream);
        reader.Close();
        Debug.Log(deserialized);
        return deserialized;
    }
}
```

Extract details of XML

```
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

[XmlRoot("WelcomePage")]
public class WelcomePage
{
    [XmlElement("Background")]
    public GenericDetails background;
    [XmlElement("MotionBand")]
    public GenericDetails motionBand;
    [XmlElement("DefaultLogo")]
    public GenericDetails defaultLogo;
    [XmlElement("WelcomeMessage")]
    public GenericDetails welcomeMessage;
    [XmlElement("VisitName")]
    public GenericDetails visitName;
    [XmlElement("VisitorName")]
    public GenericDetails[] visitorName;
    [XmlElement("Date")]
    public GenericDetails date;
    [XmlElement("Location")]
    public GenericDetails location;
    [XmlElement("CustomerLogo")]
    public GenericDetails customerLogo;
}

public class GenericDetails
{
    [XmlElement("ImagePath")]
    public string path;
    [XmlElement("Rect")]
    public string rect;
    [XmlElement("BGColor")]
    public string bgColor;
    [XmlElement("TextAlignment")]
    public string alignment;
    [XmlElement("TextColor")]
    public string textColor;
    [XmlElement("BGTransparency")]
    public float bgTransparency;
    [XmlElement("MaxFontSize")]
    public int maxFontSize;
}

public class WelcomePageSetup
{
    public WelcomePageSetup(string url)
    {
        if (!File.Exists(url))
        {
            if (!Directory.Exists(Path.GetDirectoryName(url)))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(url));

            File.WriteAllText(url, WelcomeLayout._main.welcomePageDetails, Encoding.UTF8);
        }
    }
}
```

XML File with details

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WelcomePage>

  <Background>
    <Rect>1232,0,688,1080</Rect>
    <BGColor>#000000</BGColor>
    <BGTransparency>0.7</BGTransparency>
  </Background>

  <MotionBand>
    <ImagePath>/UI/Images/MotionBand.png</ImagePath>
    <Rect>1842,0,78,1080</Rect>
  </MotionBand>

  <DefaultLogo>
    <ImagePath>/UI/Images/DefaultLogo.png</ImagePath>
    <Rect>1497,23,320,60</Rect>
  </DefaultLogo>

  <WelcomeMessage>
    <Rect>1272,942,557,126</Rect>
    <TextAlignment>mc</TextAlignment>
    <TextColor>#F0AB00</TextColor>
    <MaxFontSize>55</MaxFontSize>
  </WelcomeMessage>

  <VisitName>
    <Rect>1272,810,557,123</Rect>
    <TextAlignment>ml</TextAlignment>
    <TextColor>#ffffff</TextColor>
    <MaxFontSize>35</MaxFontSize>
  </VisitName>

  <!--Visitor name - we can have 5 visitor name display at a time-->
  <!--Visitor name 1-->
  <VisitorName>
    <Rect>1272,715,557,65</Rect>
    <TextAlignment>ml</TextAlignment>
    <TextColor>#ffffff</TextColor>
    <MaxFontSize>35</MaxFontSize>
  </VisitorName>

  <!--Visitor name 2-->
  <VisitorName>
    <Rect>1272,635,557,65</Rect>
    <TextAlignment>ml</TextAlignment>
    <TextColor>#ffffff</TextColor>
    <MaxFontSize>35</MaxFontSize>
  </VisitorName>

  <!--Visitor name 3-->
  <VisitorName>
    <Rect>1272,555,557,65</Rect>
    <TextAlignment>ml</TextAlignment>
    <TextColor>#ffffff</TextColor>
    <MaxFontSize>35</MaxFontSize>
  </VisitorName>

  <!--Visitor name 4-->
  <VisitorName>
    <Rect>1272,475,557,65</Rect>
    <TextAlignment>ml</TextAlignment>
    <TextColor>#ffffff</TextColor>
    <MaxFontSize>35</MaxFontSize>
  </VisitorName>

  <!--Visitor name 5-->
  <VisitorName>
    <Rect>1272,395,557,65</Rect>
    <TextAlignment>ml</TextAlignment>
    <TextColor>#ffffff</TextColor>
    <MaxFontSize>35</MaxFontSize>
  </VisitorName>

  <Date>
    <Rect>1272,190,557,48</Rect>
    <TextAlignment>ml</TextAlignment>
    <TextColor>#ffffff</TextColor>
    <MaxFontSize>30</MaxFontSize>
  </Date>

  <Location>
    <Rect>1272,140,557,48</Rect>
    <TextAlignment>ml</TextAlignment>
    <TextColor>#F0AB00</TextColor>
    <MaxFontSize>30</MaxFontSize>
  </Location>

  <CustomerLogo>
    <Rect>1272,274,140,70</Rect>
  </CustomerLogo>

</WelcomePage>
```

Calling it through script and path

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;
using System.Collections;

public class WelcomeLayout : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static WelcomeLayout _main;
    public WelcomePage welcomePage;

    public RectTransform background;
    public RectTransform motionBand;
    public RectTransform defaultLogo;
    public RectTransform welcomeMessage;
    public RectTransform visitName;
    public RectTransform date;
    public RectTransform location;
    public RectTransform[] visitorName;
    public RectTransform customerLogo;

    public Image backgroundBG;
    public Image motionBandImg;
    public Image defaultLogoImg;
    public Image customerLogoImg;

    public Text welcomeMessageTxt;
    public Text visitNameTxt;
    public Text dateTxt;
    public Text locationTxt;
    public Text[] visitorNameTxt;

    public GameObject[] visitorNameGObj;

    string path_base;
    string filePath;

    public GameObject welcomeScreenSet;

    public bool welcomeScreenDisplayTimer;
    public float welcomeTimer;
    public bool checkOnce;

    public bool displayVisiorNameNewSet;
    public float displayVisitorTimer;
    public float displayDuration;
    int displayFrom;

    public string currentTime;
    public string currentDay;

    public string currentTestTime;

    WelcomePageSetup welcomePageSetup;

    private void Awake()
    {
        _main = this;
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        path_base = Application.dataPath + "/Resources";

        path_base = Application.persistentDataPath+ "/Resources";
#endif

        filePath = path_base + "/WelcomeScreenTemplate.xml";

        FileInfo file = new FileInfo(filePath);

        if (file.Exists)
        {
            Debug.Log("welcome xml available");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("welcome xml not available - create xml file");
            welcomePageSetup = new WelcomePageSetup(filePath);
        }

        if (file.Exists)
        {
            welcomePage = XMLOperations.Deserialize<WelcomePage>(filePath);
        }
    }

    //Setup welcome page using XML details
    public void SetWelcomeLayout(string visit, string loc, string day, string welcome, List<string> visitor, string logo)
    {
        //Set BG
        SetRectTransform(welcomePage.background.rect, background);
        SetColor(backgroundBG, welcomePage.background.bgColor, welcomePage.background.bgTransparency);

        //Set motion band
        SetSpriteOnImage(motionBandImg, path_base + welcomePage.motionBand.path);
        SetRectTransform(welcomePage.motionBand.rect, motionBand);

        //Set default logo
        SetSpriteOnImage(defaultLogoImg, path_base + welcomePage.defaultLogo.path);
        SetRectTransform(welcomePage.defaultLogo.rect, defaultLogo);

        //Set Welcome message
        welcomeMessageTxt.text = welcome;
        SetRectTransform(welcomePage.welcomeMessage.rect, welcomeMessage);
        SetColor(welcomeMessageTxt, welcomePage.welcomeMessage.textColor);
        AlignTextAndMaxFont(welcomeMessageTxt, welcomePage.welcomeMessage.alignment, welcomePage.welcomeMessage.maxFontSize);

        //Set visit name
        //byte[] bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(visit);
        //visit = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
        visitNameTxt.text = visit.ToUpper();
        SetRectTransform(welcomePage.visitName.rect, visitName);
        SetColor(visitNameTxt, welcomePage.visitName.textColor);
        AlignTextAndMaxFont(visitNameTxt, welcomePage.visitName.alignment, welcomePage.visitName.maxFontSize);

        //Set date
        //dateTxt.text = day;
        currentDay = day;
        SetRectTransform(welcomePage.date.rect, date);
        SetColor(dateTxt, welcomePage.date.textColor);
        AlignTextAndMaxFont(dateTxt, welcomePage.date.alignment, welcomePage.date.maxFontSize);

        //Set location
        locationTxt.text = loc;
        SetRectTransform(welcomePage.location.rect, location);
        SetColor(locationTxt, welcomePage.location.textColor);
        AlignTextAndMaxFont(locationTxt, welcomePage.location.alignment, welcomePage.location.maxFontSize);
}
```

}

Please do check the script and help me out to resolve the issue. Its working fine in standalone builds, I can edit the XML details, its reflecting the UI. In iOS build its not de-serializing, the function with XML details got error because of details not de-serializing and retrieved.

Exception shown in iOS - Xcode

```
welcome xml available

WelcomeLayout:Start()



(Filename: /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/Debug.bindings.h Line: 43)



NotSupportedException: /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/External/il2cpp/il2cpp/libil2cpp/icalls/mscorlib/System.Reflection.Emit/AssemblyBuilder.cpp(20) : Unsupported internal call for IL2CPP:AssemblyBuilder::basic_init - System.Reflection.Emit is not supported.

  at System.Reflection.Emit.AssemblyBuilder..ctor (System.Reflection.AssemblyName n, System.String directory, System.Reflection.Emit.AssemblyBuilderAccess access, System.Boolean corlib_internal) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 

  at System.AppDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly (System.Reflection.AssemblyName name, System.Reflection.Emit.AssemblyBuilderAccess access, System.String dir, System.Security.Policy.Evidence evidence, System.Security.PermissionSet requiredPermissions, System.Security.PermissionSet optionalPermissions, System.Security.PermissionSet refusedPermissions, System.Boolean isSynchronized) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 

  at System.AppDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly (System.Reflection.AssemblyName name, System.Reflection.Emit.AssemblyBuilderAccess access) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 

  at System.Xml.Serialization.TempAssembly.GenerateRefEmitAssembly (System.Xml.Serialization.XmlMapping[] xmlMappings, System.Type[] types, System.String defaultNamespace, System.Security.Policy.Evidence evidence) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 

  at System.Xml.Serialization.TempAssembly..ctor (System.Xml.Serialization.XmlMapping[] xmlMappings, System.Type[] types, System.String defaultNamespace, System.String location, System.Security.Policy.Evidence evidence) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 

  at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.GenerateTempAssembly (System.Xml.Serialization.XmlMapping xmlMapping, System.Type type, System.String defaultNamespace) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 

  at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer..ctor (System.Type type, System.String defaultNamespace) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 

  at XMLOperations.Load[T] (System.String path) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 

  at WelcomeLayout.Start () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0
```

Comment: If you received error, you have to add the error to your question

Comment: In editor, I am checking with Application.datapath - every thing working fine. In iOS device I added the Resources file with xml through iTunes file share, xml details not reflected there. Could n't see any error explicitly.

Comment: Connect your iOS device to your computer then use xcode to check for any error or exception

Comment: Added the exception details in with the question

Comment: I am using 2018.2.0f2 version of Unity

Comment: @Programmer - I have switched the API compatibility level to .NET Standard 2.0 from 4.x, its working. Thanks for your time and advice.

Comment: I was about put answer then saw yours but the issue is more of IL2CPP. The .NET 2 version do not support the Emit function. Changing it to 4.x should fix the issue.

Comment: @Programmer its working for me Script Runtime Version is 4.x, API compatibility is .NET standard 2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've hit a limitation with the .NET profile implementation Unity uses for AOT platforms (like iOS). In Unity 2018.3 and later (not yet released), we've corrected this issue, so that any Api Compatibility Level option in Unity will use an AOT-friendly class library implementation.

In Unity 2018.2 and earlier, you'll need to use the .NET Standard 2.0 Api Compatibility Level, as you determined.

In general, the .NET Standard 2.0 Api Compatibility Level is the right choice. It contains most of the APIs used in most Unity projects, and it will generate much smaller code that the .NET 4.x Api Compatibility Level.

Answer (score 0):

I have switched the API compatibility level to .NET Standard 2.0 from 4.x, its working